# Route [dealer] not defined. in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I defined my route but it is not showing that **Route [dealer] not defined**.

```
Route::resource('/dealer', DealerController::class);
```

This is my controller where there is index, create and store method is in same page.

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return view('dealer', compact('users'));
}

public function create()
{
    $dealers = Dealer::all();
    return view('dealer', compact('dealers'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'name_of_firm' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'number' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
        'name_of_firm' => $request->input('name_of_firm'),
        'address' => $request->input('address'),
        'number' => $request->input('number'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('dealer')->withSuccess('done');
}
```

Comment: it is not `dealer` it will be `dealer.index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller

Look at the example from the documentation. There exists no such route in your ressource controller.

Depending on what you want you either have to use `dealer.index`, `dealer.show` or `dealer.edit`

Normally you would also use the plural form and not the singular form of the word.